# laravel save json to database mysql

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a problem saving a json result to a table in the mysql database.

Json Return

```
{ "retorno": {
  "status_processamento": 3,
    "status": "OK",
    "pagina": "1",
    "numero_paginas": "1",
    "pedidos": [
      {
        "pedido": {
          "id": 123456,
          "numero": 123456,
          "numero_ecommerce": "12",
          "data_pedido": "01/01/2013",
          "data_prevista": "10/01/2013",
          "nome": "Cliente Teste",
          "valor": "100.25",
          "id_vendedor": "123456",
          "nome_vendedor": "Vendedor Teste",
          "situacao": "Atendido"
        }
      },
      {
        "pedido": {
          "id": 123456,
          "numero": 123458,
          "numero_ecommerce": "15",
          "data_pedido": "01/01/2013",
          "data_prevista": "10/01/2013",
          "nome": "Cliente Teste 3",
          "valor": "50.25",
          "id_vendedor": "",
          "nome_vendedor": "",
          "situacao": "Aberto"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Rating extends Model
{

 protected $fillable = [

          'ratingKey'

      ];

}
```

Controller

```
  $data = json_decode($response, true);

  Rating::create(
  [ 'ratingKey'  => $data['retorno']['pedidos'][0]['pedido']['id']   ]);
```

this code works perfectly but only saves one answer from json and i would like to save all the answers and if i change the code to

```
'ratingKey'  => $data['retorno']['pedidos'][]['pedido']['id']
```

I get this error

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException
>   Cannot use [] for reading

Comment: This syntax: `$data['retorno']['pedidos'][]['pedido']['id']` won't work. You'll need to use some kind of loop iterate the data and construct a viable array for insertion, or insert one-by-one in said loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to iterate over your `$data['retorno']['pedidos']` array creating a structured array of arrays to be passed to the `Rating::insert()` method ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#inserts)).

```
$data = json_decode($response, true);

$ratingKeys = [];
foreach($data['retorno']['pedidos'] as $o){
    $ratingKeys[] = ['ratingKey' => $o['pedido']['id']];
}

Rating::insert($ratingKeys);
```

Comment: Call to undefined method App\Rating::createMany()

Comment: @LucasSilva Updated answer.

Comment: const VERSION = '6.8.0';